# Importing Signing and Verifying key for JWT RSA algorithm in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm working on a django rest api application that uses JWTAuthentication using [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt). Since the RSA algorithm is in use, the signing and verifying key needs to be set.

The implementation below worked for me.

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'SIGNING_KEY': open('jwtRS256.key').read() if os.path.isfile('./jwtRS256.key') else None,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': open('jwtRS256.key.pub').read() if os.path.isfile('./jwtRS256.key.pub') else None,
}
```

After upgrading to django 3 and running `py -Wa manage.py test`. This are some of the warning messages being displayed.

```
D:\path\to\settings.py:398: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='jwtRS256.key' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
  'SIGNING_KEY': open('jwtRS256.key').read() if os.path.isfile('./jwtRS256.key') else None,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
D:\path\to\\settings.py:399: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='jwtRS256.key.pub' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
  'VERIFYING_KEY': open('jwtRS256.key.pub').read() if os.path.isfile('./jwtRS256.key.pub') else None,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried an alternative to solve this issue but it seems to break the app when authenticating users. This is the attempted solution.

```
def get_file(file_url):
    if os.path.isfile(file_url):
        with open(file_url) as f:
            return f
            
    return None


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'SIGNING_KEY': get_file('./jwtRS256.key'),
    'VERIFYING_KEY': get_file('./jwtRS256.key.pub')
}
```

This doesn't work when trying to log in and returns a 500 with `TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to read the file.

```
def get_file(file_url):
    if os.path.isfile(file_url):
        with open(file_url) as f:
            return f.read()

    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
def get_file(file_url):
     file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_url)    
     if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path,'rb') as f:
            return f.read()

    return None
```